# C++ Overload Operator = for Pointers does not compile

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a template Class with an Operator Overload for =
so far it works for non pointer elements, but if I try it for pointers it does not compile

My template Class:

```
template <class T>
class IBag {
public:
    T _val;
    void Set(T val) { _val = val; } 
    T Get() { return _val; }

    IBag& operator=(T val) {
        this->Set(val);
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() {
        return this->Get();
    }
};
```

How it works using it:

```
class IBagExample
{
    static void showExample() {
        IBag<QString>* bag = new IBag<QString>();
        bag->Set(QString("Blub"));
        *bag = QString("Blub");
    }
};
```

how it does not compile:

```
class IBagExample
{
    static void showExample() {
        IBag<QString*>* pbag = new IBag<QString*>();
        pbag->Set(new QString("Blub")); // This works
        pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This doesn't works ?!?
    }
};
```

The compiler Error I get is :

```
error: assigning to 'IBag<QString *> *' from incompatible type 'QString *'
    pbag = new QString("Blub");
         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So my question is how do I get this work, I expected that the overload of the = operator will force c++ to pipe all requests including the new request to my custom function if its not the new constructor of the current class (so IBag* x = new IBag() will allocate IBag but x = new QString("sdjf"); will be forwarded to my custom overload as it is a different Object)

(Note:The IBag example is just a simplification of the Code I am trying to implement.)

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Pointer assignment cannot be "overloaded", it is already defined. `T *ptr;  ptr = foo;` makes `ptr` have the value of `foo`, it does not call any functions.

Comment: You seem to have a few different questions in your question. `T foo = bar;` is not an assignment invocation , it is a declaration with initializer. Also it is not a pointer assignment.  Your section "In the result of all this I want to do..." has nothing to do with the earlier parts of your question where you say it didn't work. Can you re-write your question to clarify exactly what you want to do?

Comment: try `*pbag = new QString("Blub");` you cannot overload `operator=()` for pointer types, so you have to unreference it to `value type`

Comment: @Matt McNabbSo no chance of doing this or something similar ? Maybe a second new operator maybe IBag<QString*> pbag = newVal QString("Blub"); (like I think in Objective C) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After various changes in my Code using your suggestions and reviewing what I need, I have following Result :

```
class IBagExample
{
   void showExample() {
        IBag<QString*> pbag;
        pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This works !
    }
};
```

This does compile and work, but what does not work is following and I will ask this in another follow up question:

```
class IBagExample
{
   void showExample() {
        IBag<QString*> pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This doesn't work !
    }
};
```

So thanks a lot for your help!

Follow up Question: [C++ Overload Operator = for Pointers does not work/compile properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606231/c-overload-operator-for-pointers-does-not-work-compile-properly)

Comment: "Asche auf mein Haupt" - As you will see in the Follow up, I just needed (a cup of coffee and) to add a T* constructor to IBag as the operator definition is not for construction.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it well:

```
error: assigning to 'IBag<QString *> *' from incompatible type 'QString *'
    pbag = new QString("Blub");
         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

`pbag` is a pointer, not an `IBag`. You overloaded `operator =` for `IBag`, not for `IBag *` (which is not possible).

This should compile because it calls your operator:

`*pbag = new QString("Blub");`

Comment: see my own answer, as I had to review what I need

Answer (score 2):

Well

```
pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This doesn't works ?!?
```

try

```
*pbag = new QString("Blub");
```

Since `pbag` is of type `IBag*` which is not of type `IBag`.
You're esentially calling the assignment operator of `IBag*` which is built-in I guess but probably "looks" like

```
Ibag*& operator=(Ibag* const &);
```

which is not your `IBag& operator=(T val);` since that one is part of `IBag` not `IBag*`.

You cannot alter the C++ pointer types and `operator=` must be a member function of the specified type.

and

```
IBag<QString> bag = QString("Blub");
IBag<QString*> pbag = new QString("Blub");
```

do not work because you don't have a custom constructor from `T`.

Comment: *pbag I already know and is what I dont want, it means I have to change already existing Code

Comment: @aqm You're probably right. You cannot define a custom assignment operator for pointer types but the question comments already state that well enough.

Comment: see my own answer, as I had to review what I need

Answer (score 0):

You overload operator for a class to be used by an object. Here pBag is just a pointer and not an object. C++ standard ISO/IEC 14882 § 13.5.3 mention an example which takes pointers, but used with de-referencing (by *).

Comment: see my own answer, as I had to review what I need