# C++ Overload Operator = for Pointers does not work/compile properly

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I am trying to implement a template Class with an Operator Overload for =
so far it works for non pointer elements. For Pointer Elements it doesn't work exactly as I expect it to, so my question is why this is sow and how do I force c++ do it as I want.

My template Class:

```
template <class T>
class IBag {
public:
    T _val;
    void Set(T val) { _val = val; } 
    T Get() { return _val; }

    IBag& operator=(T val) {
        this->Set(val);
        return *this;
    }

    operator T() {
        return this->Get();
    }
};
```

How it works using the IBag Class:

```
class IBagExample
{
   void showExample() {
        IBag<QString*> pbag;
        pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This works !
    }
};
```

how it does not compile:

```
class IBagExample
{
   void showExample() {
        IBag<QString*> pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This doesn't compile !
    }
};
```

The compiler Error I get is :

```
error: no viable conversion from 'QString *' to 'IBag<QString *>'
    IBag<QString*> pbag2 = new QString("Blub");
                   ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

For me it seems the same, maybe I need to tell the compiler something to understand what type of pointer is now going to be pushed into the pbag. But I have no Idea how to do that.

Using the operator overload like

```
IBag<QString*> pbag; pbag = new QString("Blub"); // This does compile !
```

seems just ridiculous.

***(Note:The IBag example is just a simplification of the Code I am trying to implement.)***

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Why don't you just add a constructor taking `T` as argument? Then you have IBag<QString*> pbag( new QString() );

Comment: `IBag<QString*> pbag = new QString("Blub");` requires a constructor of the form `IBag(T val);` to work (although you may want it to be explicit (then `IBag<QString*> pbag (new QString("Blub"));`)

Comment: @Nial / stijn: Yeah thanks, thats the answer, I am so stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IBag<QString*> pbag = new QString("Blub");
```

This doesn't actually call the assignment operator, it calls a constructor. You need to define that something like:

```
template <class T>
class IBag {
public:
    IBag( const IBag& rhs )
    {
        // ....
    }

};
```

or:

```
    IBag( const T& rhs )
    {
        // ....
    }
```

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks for letting me know why you downvoted. Yes, there are numerous alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment is not construction. A copy assignment operator doesn't handle construction (even if the `=` in an assignment looks suspiciously like the `=` in a declaration with copy initialization). Either define a suitable constructor or use C++11 braces initialization, e.g.

```
auto pbag2 = IBag<QString*>{ new QString("Blub") };
```

Disclaimer: code untouched by compiler's hands.

---

Issues with the code:

- setters and getters are in general a design smell, a Java-ism, even if they sometimes are useful,
- public data members are also a design smell for a class with an invariant (such as non-null pointers),
- a public data member with a setter and a getter, that's not meaningful,
- you need to take charge of copying (rule of three, rule of zero), and
- you need to make a decision on supporting constness, and do The Right Thing™ (whatever it may be).

---

For a logical interface, as this is, also consider adding a virtual destructor. That enables RTTI via the interface. E.g. deleting an object via the interface, or dynamic casting to some other interface or implementation class.

Comment: As I stated the IBag Class is an example therefore it is not complete and correctly defined. The Get/Set Method should be protected and the Datamember private. The original Class in my project sometimes show a Set method sometimes not (it is an implementation of Properties and Readonly Properties) ...

Comment: @aqm: you should post **real code**, anything else just misleads. now you're saying that the fictitious code you're posting is *not even representative*, in your own opinion. obviously you don't understand why that's wrong, but take my word for it: it's very, very wrong, and the net is therefore full of small tutorials on how to post, including [the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/posting-code.html) (do click that link and read that now, please).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf - Not real code, but it adequate described the problem well enough for it to be answered. aqm did declare in the question that the posted code is a simplification. Switching to brace initialization will not resolve the issue.

Comment: @ScottLangham: switching to brace initialization does indeed resolve the *stated* issue. you can just try it. that was much of my point, which your comment is in response to. it does not resolve the *real* issue, because as explained in comments by the OP the real code is *fundamentally* different. posting non-real code is ungood.

Comment: @Cheersandhth: Its a project for a customer so I am not allowed to post the original code! So anyhow you can just waste time questioning how to post right or just help like others did.